# Tool to search source code for strings which can contain quotes, double quotes, a parens, equal sign.. etc?

Tags: search, full-text-search

I use tools like dtSearch and File Locator Lite to search my local source code files for words and they work fine.

However sometimes I need to search for a phrase like 'Session["cutid"] =' (without single quotes)  and do an exact match which includes the double quotes, the space and the equal sign and my search tools don't return anything even though I know the phrase exists.

Can you recommend a search tool which can find the phrase above and if it requires some special syntax, write the syntax. Thanks.

Addition: 
Prefer not using regular expressions because I am not good at them. Just want to do a match for whatever I enter in the search term.

Answer (score 0):

I use NetBeans,their search in projects feature allows you to search by regular expression.  I think most other IDEs also support this. Or you could use grep, and other unix tools.

Answer (score 0):

Our Source Code Search Engine can do this.  It uses language-specific scanners to break the source code into language elements (identifiers, strings, numbers, comments, keywords, whitespace, etc.) in completely language accurate way (e.g., understands the escape sequences in strings!). You can then formulate queries over those language atoms.  (I assume your example is PHP ; SCSE handles PHP including all the complicated stuff inside string literals, Java, ...)

The query for your specific search:

```
   I=Session '[' S=cutid ']' '='
```

What the query says is, Find an I(dentifier) whose exact name is 'Session', followed by an operator '[' followed by S(tring) whose exact content is 'cutid', followed by the operator ']' followed by '='.   Whitespace and interwoven comments are skipped, so this can be broken across multiple line boundaries.  If you wanted any identifier containing 'Sess', you'd write a wildcard for the identifier, e.g.,  I=*Sess*.  You can use a regular expression instead of a wildcard for I (e.g, =\.*Sess.*\) or S constraints, or if you insist, perform a search using only a regular expression.

The SCSE offers a GUI; any found hits are shown as single lines, and a single click will pull up the source code file containing the hit.  Configured slightly, an additional click will drop you into your favorite editor at the point of the hit.

The SCSE indexes your code base, so the searches are extremely fast, even for huge code bases.  It can handle multiple, mixed languages (e.g., PHP, JavaScript, ...).

Comment: I just spent minutes to find the product on the web. You didn't provide a link. No price on the product page and no price on the Prices page. Why is the basic information so hard to find!?

Comment: I'd be happy to provide a web link, but the SO "moderators" don't like me posting website links. Complain to them about making you go find it; I think that's stupid but it isn't my choice. For downloads, try the "download" link under "Support".